# Code for ignoring particular value in column of dataframe for taking mode?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, group-by

**This is the code for dataFrame**

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

```
Data_Frame1 = {
  "company": ["A","B","C","A","A","B","C","B","C"],
  "employee": [10,12,13,10,51,11,12,12,12],
  "salary":[2,"unknown",4,"unknown",5,"unknown",8,8,4],
  "compartment":["madhyapradesh","uttarpradesh","gujarat","madhyapradesh","uttarpradesh","uttarpradesh","gujarat","gujarat","madhyapradesh"]
} 
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(Data_Frame1)
df_1
```

**it's output is like**
[This is dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8dGZ.png)

**For mode I have written code like this**

```
emp=df_1.groupby('company')[['employee','salary',"compartment"]].agg(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)[0])
emp
```

**And it's output is like this**

[The output of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N8VQ.png)

**Here I have replaced null values by writting unknow and in this company B has three values corresponding to salary column like ["unknown',"unknown",8] but as it is taking mode so it is taking unknown as result but I want it should take 8 as mode because here I have replaced null value to unknown So what should be the code for implementing this functionality**

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `unknown` for avoid count `mode`, if all values per groups are `unknown` your solution failed, so used `iter` with `next` trick for get first mode if exist else `NaN`:

```
emp=(df_1.replace('unknown', np.nan)
        .groupby('company')[['employee','salary',"compartment"]]
        .agg(lambda x: next(iter(x.mode()), np.nan)))
print (emp)
         employee  salary    compartment
company                                 
A              10     2.0  madhyapradesh
B              12     8.0   uttarpradesh
C              12     4.0        gujarat
```

You can test it in new data:

```
Data_Frame1 = {
  "company": ["A","B","C","A","A","B","C","B","C"],
  "employee": [10,12,13,10,51,11,12,12,12],
  "salary":["unknown","unknown",4,"unknown",'unknown',"unknown",8,8,4],
  "compartment":["madhyapradesh","uttarpradesh","gujarat","madhyapradesh","uttarpradesh","uttarpradesh","gujarat","gujarat","madhyapradesh"]
    }

#salary fr A company is only unknown
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(Data_Frame1)
print (df_1)
  company  employee   salary    compartment
0       A        10  unknown  madhyapradesh
1       B        12  unknown   uttarpradesh
2       C        13        4        gujarat
3       A        10  unknown  madhyapradesh
4       A        51  unknown   uttarpradesh
5       B        11  unknown   uttarpradesh
6       C        12        8        gujarat
7       B        12        8        gujarat
8       C        12        4  madhyapradesh
```

---

```
emp=(df_1.replace('unknown', np.nan)
        .groupby('company')[['employee','salary',"compartment"]]
        .agg(lambda x: next(iter(x.mode()), np.nan)))
print (emp)
         employee  salary    compartment
company                                 
A              10     NaN  madhyapradesh
B              12     8.0   uttarpradesh
C              12     4.0        gujarat

emp=(df_1.replace('unknown', np.nan)
          .groupby('company')[['employee','salary',"compartment"]]
          .agg(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)[0]))

print (emp)
#KeyError: 0
```

Comment: can you explain me how do it works?

Comment: @GALAXYA50 - Not sure if understand, your original solution not working? Why is replaced `null` to `unknown` if need avoid count mode?